# Git-svn: determine number of commits ahead or behind

Tags: git-svn

Is there a way with git-svn to determine how many commits ahead or behind I am?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean how many commits have been made in Subversion since you took the branch you're working on, or how many commits you've made in your branch that aren't in the Subversion repository?

Comment: Yeah, behind = how many commits have been made in subversion since I either did an initial pull (clone) or since I've done a rebase.  ahead = just what you said: the number of commits I've made using the git commit that I haven't git svn dcommit-ted.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not directly. What you can do, though, is find out how far ahead and/or behind you are from the local copy of the Subversion repository.

So start with `git svn fetch` to bring your local repository up-to-date, and go from there.

To find out how many commits there are in the branch you're currently on, but which haven't been committed to the Subversion server, there's a whole bunch of tricks, but the most obvious one is to run `git svn dcommit --dry-run`, and see how many commits are listed to be pushed to Subversion.

Short version: run `git svn dcommit --dry-run | grep diff-tree | wc -l`.

To work out how many commits are in the Subversion repository, but not in the branch you're working on, you need to first work out or know the name of the Subversion branch you're working from.  You can probably work this out from the first line of `git svn dcommit --dry-run`, or from `git log -1 --grep git-svn-id`.

Say your branch is `master`, and the parent Subversion branch is `remotes/svn/trunk`.  You can then run `git svn rev-list master..remotes/svn/trunk | wc -l` to count all the commits that are in the remote trunk and not in your branch.

As an alternative to all the above, when you create a branch, specify it as tracking a Subversion branch. For example, when I create a local branch based on the remote trunk, I create it as follows:

```
git checkout -b new-branch-name -t remotes/svn/trunk
```

Now, whenever I do `git status` or `git checkout new-branch-name`, the output will include a line telling me just how far ahead or behind each branch is relative to the other.

For a branch that already exists, you can set it up to track a Subversion branch as below:

```
git branch --set-upstream existing-branch remotes/svn/trunk
```

Comment: Thank you for that, sir.  And especially thank you for the -set-upstream tip.  (Although, it gave me a warning saying that will be deprecated in favor of --set-upstream-to=, which I ended up using.)

Comment: Oh - and one question.  Doesn't the git svn fetch do a pull, so that I won't be behind by any commits any more?

Comment: Also, this command:  "git svn dcommit --dry-run" yields the following error:update-index --refresh: command returned error: 1

Comment: Nevermind on the error.  It's because I had unstaged changes.  Which makes me think this method might not quite work (since I'm trying to build an output display that will always tell me where I am, even with unstaged changes).

Comment: No, `git svn fetch` does a fetch, not a pull or rebase; you'll have all the remote commits locally, but your commits won't be based on the new remote commits. For that, you need a `git rebase`, or you can do a `git svn rebase` to effectively do both steps at once (although `git svn rebase` does a `git svn fetch --parent`, _not_ `git svn fetch`).

Comment: Also, I didn't know `--set-upstream` was becoming obsolete; that's not warned about in my version of Git (1.7.9). Although my version is somewhat elderly now, so that's not massively surprising.

Comment: Any thoughts about doing this without doing a dry run dcommit?

Comment: Mr A: sure; I just use that as a convenient way to get the parent branch and the number of commits. You can get both by just looking at `git log`.

Answer (score 0):

In git >= 1.9, there seems to be a bug that prevents using `--set-upstream/--set-upstream-to`

It doesn't work for me either in git 2.23.0

The workaround is to modify the .gitconfig manually : [how-to-set-upstream-branch-in-git-svn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25270876/11267540)